# Program Hangs while executing

Tags: c#, algorithm, console

I am having a problem where my program executes and then just hangs somewhere during execution. I basically want to know what causes this.

```
for (long i = maxNumber; i > 2; i--)
{
    IsPrime = true;
    for (long g = 2; g < i; g++)
    {
        long temp = i % g;
        if (temp == 0)
        {
            IsPrime = false;                            
            break;
        }
    }
    if (IsPrime == true)
    {
        largestPrimeFactor = i;                        
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: inputs for when it hangs? I haven't looked hard, but are you sure it isn't just *taking a really long time* ? O(N^2) is very long for large enough N.

Comment: What's the value of `maxNumber`?

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Slow indeed and gets slower the larger maxNumber is. The algorithm is N-Squared, meaning for 10 numbers it does around 100 tests, but for 1000 number it does around 1 million tests and so on!

Comment: `if (IsPrime == true)` change this to `if (IsPrime)` for cleaner code. Ifs are already boolean, no use adding an extra comparison in.

Comment: Of course, testing it for all the even numbers is pointless *anyway*; but even taking those away, it would still be O(N^2)

Comment: in 1st for condition should be changed into: for (long g = 2; g *g  < i; g++). it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I tried it correctly, your code is trying to find the largest prime between 0 and maxNumber. Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes for finding all prime numbers between 0 and the square root of maxNumber. Then, you can iterate from maxNumber to 0 for a number indivisible by all of the prime numbers you've just found.

EDIT : 
Tried this

```
            var sqrtMax = (int)Math.Sqrt(maxNumber);
            var primeCandidates = Enumerable.Range(2, sqrtMax-1)
             .ToDictionary(number => number, isComposite => false);

            foreach (var number in primeCandidates.Keys.ToArray())
            {
                if (primeCandidates[number])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(2, sqrtMax / number - 1).Select(times => number * times),multiples=>
                    primeCandidates[multiples] = true);
            }
            var primeList = primeCandidates.Where(number => !number.Value).Select(pair=>pair.Key).ToArray();
            var maxPrime = maxNumber;


            while (primeList.AsParallel().Any(prime=> maxPrime%prime==0))
            {
                maxPrime--;
            }
```

and it find maxPrime in less than 3 seconds for maxNumber = 600881475134 (the parallelization was because I thought it would take long time)

Answer (score 3):

This algorthm probably doesn't hang. Depending on the value of `maxnumber` it can take a **very** long time to go through the loops.

Comment: The value of max number is 600881475134. But i output a Console.WriteLine("==="); to see if it is still looping. The thing is it will print the output a few times then stop. Which makes me think it is hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Your program ´hangs´ because its thread is being used by the loop you posted. This means your cannot take any other commands until the loop is finished.
If you want to prevent this behavior, use different threads instead to execute your code.

A different algorithm may increase performance, but eventually you will still experience a ´hang´ depending on the time it takes to execute.